# TYPO3 content on one page order by position in pagetree

Tags: select, typo3, typoscript

I'm showing all content from the subpages on one page:

```
lib.allPid = COA
lib.allPid {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        #entryLevel = 1
                special = directory
                special.value = 115
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            expAll = 1
            NO.doNotShowLink = 1
            NO.allStdWrap.field = uid
            NO.allStdWrap.wrap = |,
        }
        2 < .1
    }
}

lib.allContent = CONTENT
lib.allContent {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        pidInList.cObject < lib.allPid
                where = colPos = 0
                orderBy = pid DESC
    }
}
```

Here the content is ordere by pid DESC. But I'd like to order the content from the subpages by their position in the pagetree. So that the user can define his own ordering.

I tried:

```
lib.allContent = CONTENT
lib.allContent {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList.cObject < lib.allPid
    leftjoin = pages ON (tt_content.pid = pages.pid)
                where = tt_content.colPos = 0                    
                orderBy = pages.sorting ASC
  }
}
```

Didn't work...

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on a good way, but you made the join wrong.

In your code it is `tt_content.pid = pages.pid`, and this one is wrong. The `pid` value in `tt_content` is the `uid` from the `pages`.

You need to change your script so:

```
lib.allContent = CONTENT
lib.allContent {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList.cObject < lib.allPid
    leftjoin = pages ON (tt_content.pid = pages.uid)
                where = tt_content.colPos = 0                    
                orderBy = pages.sorting ASC
  }
}
```

I tested it, and it worked on a test instance.

Comment: Great, it works! Thanks so much! I searched the internet for a description of the TYPO3 database tables and their relations but didn't find anything. Do you know where I can find this database documentation?

Comment: I added a related question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37344614/typo3-show-content-from-subpages-inlcuding-css-classes