# TYPO3 show content from subpages inlcuding css classes

Tags: css, typo3, typoscript

With the following typoscript I get all content from the subpages on one page:

```
lib.allPid = COA
lib.allPid {
  10 = HMENU
  10 {        
    special = directory
    special.value = 2
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      expAll = 1
      NO.doNotShowLink = 1
      NO.allStdWrap.field = uid
      NO.allStdWrap.wrap = |,
    }
    2 < .1
  }
}

lib.allContent = CONTENT
lib.allContent {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    pidInList.cObject < lib.allPid
    leftjoin = pages ON (tt_content.pid = pages.uid)
                where = tt_content.colPos = 0                    
                orderBy = pages.sorting ASC
  }
}
```

But its not copying the tt_content wrap defined by the layout selectbox in the content element:

```
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.20.40 = CASE
tt_content.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.20.40 {
    key.field = layout

    1 = TEXT
    1.value = tag-1

    2 = TEXT
    2.value = tag-2

    3 = TEXT
    3.value = tag-3

    4 = TEXT
    4.value = tag-4

    5 = TEXT
    5.value = tag-5

    6 = TEXT
    6.value = tag-6

    7 = TEXT
    7.value = tag-7
}
```

I tried to add the wrap to the `lib.allContent` element like this, but it didn't work:

```
lib.allContent.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.20.40 = CASE
lib.allContent.stdWrap.innerWrap.cObject.default.20.40 {
    key.field = layout

    1 = TEXT
    1.value = tag-1

    2 = TEXT
    2.value = tag-2

    3 = TEXT
    3.value = tag-3

    4 = TEXT
    4.value = tag-4

    5 = TEXT
    5.value = tag-5

    6 = TEXT
    6.value = tag-6

    7 = TEXT
    7.value = tag-7
}
```

Does anybody know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
I found a solution (or better: workaround) without typoscript. I insert the contents from the subpages with "New content element - Special Elements - Insert Record" manually one by one. Then, everything is copied. This solutions requires a little more user input but fits perfectly to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

give a try to [vhs ViewHelper](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/vhs) it'll give you exact output what you want I mean default wrap and at all.

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}

<v:page.menu pageUid="2" includeSpacers="0" resolveExclude="1">
    <f:for each="{menu}" as="contentList" iteration="Iteration">
        <div id="uid{contentList.uid}" class="inner-page-content-of-pageUid-2">
            <v:content.render column="0" pageUid="{contentList.uid}" />
        </div>
    </f:for>
</v:page.menu>
```

something more about [vhs ViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master.html)

Comment: Thanks for your input! I gave you +1 for the idea, but i'd rather go without an additional extension. So I found a way to do it with TYPO3 core features (see edit in post).

Comment: @user3532637 Thanks for your valuable +1, that would be fine you got the solution what you want with core :) but instead of putting solution in question, you should give it to in answer so people can found as solution.

Comment: True, but it's not a direct answer / solution to the original problem but more like a workaround. So may be one day someone will give an answer in pure typoscript, who knows :) Thanks again for your support!